# Why is my async pipe not showing the observable, while a console.log is working?

Tags: angular, observable, async-pipe

I have the following code:

```
    this.projects$ = new Subject();

    let observableProjects: ProjectList = [];
    this.userObject$.subscribe( async (user) => {
      observableProjects = [];
      for (let projectID of user.ownedProjects) {
        await this.firestore.collection('projects').doc(projectID).ref.get().then( async (doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            let tempProject = doc.data() as Project;
            let tempDate = tempProject.startDate as unknown as { nanoseconds: number; seconds: number; };
            let tempLocation = tempProject.location as unknown as string;
            let observerProject: Project = new Project(
                projectID,
                tempProject.fullName,
                tempProject.shortName,
                tempProject.ownerID,
                tempProject.lastOwnerID,
                tempDate.seconds,
                tempProject.duration,
                tempProject.logo,
                tempProject.status,
                tempProject.categoryID,
                tempLocation,
                [],
                tempProject.timelinePosts);
            await this.firestore.collection('projects/' + projectID + '/descriptions').ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
              snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                observerProject.description.push(doc.data() as Description);
              });
              observableProjects.push(observerProject);
            });
          }
        });
      }
      this.projects$.next(observableProjects);
    });
```

When I simply subscribe and console.log it as so:

```
    this.projects$.subscribe((list) => {
      console.log(list);
    });
```

Then, there it outputs the list which is needed to the console. But in my HTML document I have the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showProjects && (projects$ | async) as projectList; else loading">
    <div class="ion-margin-top ion-padding-top" id="ownedProjectsCardContainer" overflow-scroll="true">
      <ion-card *ngFor="let project of projectList" class="ion-margin-top">
        <img width="100%" [src]="project.logo" />
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-subtitle>{{ project.startDateString }} - <span class="{{ project.status ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}">{{ project.status ? 'ACTIVE' : 'INACTIVE' }}</span></ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-title>{{ project.fullName }}</ion-card-title>
          <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end">
            <ion-fab-button (click)="goToEditProject(project.id)">
              <ion-icon name="pencil-outline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-fab-button>
          </ion-fab>
        </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>

      <ng-container *ngIf="(projects$ | async)?.length == 0" [ngTemplateOutlet]="noProjects"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #loading>
    <ion-progress-bar type="indeterminate"></ion-progress-bar>
  </ng-template>
```

However, no matter what the project observable returns, angular just shows the loading component. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the variable `showProjects`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: @DmitryS. showProjects is just a boolean. I've tried removing it from the *ngIf and it still has the same issues.

Comment: One Suggestion: please use projects$.asObservable() while we subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(projects$ | async) as projectList; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="showProjects; else loading">
  ...
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Please use the individually two `*ngIf` conditions when you use the value of the observable.